# Kali linux in android

Tags: kali-linux

[image]

I have installed Kali Linux successfully using Linux deploy. I get this error when I run the browser in VNC Viewer. Please help me.

Comment: you could have provided a screenshot of just the error and not the entire screen, or better yet, just provided the text

Comment: I'm confused: you run the browser in VNC viewer? What browser would run in VNC?

Comment: Then is it possible to install a browser in it?

Comment: You need to describe *your* environment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using Linux Deploy on Android you have a lot of images to install. Kali is one of them. It installs also a SSH server and a VNC server to connect to your Linux.

In first instance you should update your system as normal using `apt update && apt dist-upgrade` and will see if error disappear. You can also check the file of your error. The error is saying that file has a bad "structure". Usually, files with ".desktop" extension are shortcuts and they should have this structure (I'll put an example of one of my desktop shortcuts):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=sqlninja
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=sh -c "sqlninja;${SHELL:-bash}"
Icon=kali-sqlninja.png
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=04-database-assessment;
X-Kali-Package=sqlninja
```

Check it to know if your shortcut has the right structure or complete it if is not ok. You can delete it also if you are not using it and try to create it again.

A firefox (if it is your browser) shortcut has a little bit more complicated structure because of languages:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox ESR
Name[bg]=Firefox ESR
Name[ca]=Firefox ESR
Name[cs]=Firefox ESR
Name[es]=Firefox ESR
Name[fa]=Firefox ESR
Name[fi]=Firefox ESR
Name[fr]=Firefox ESR
Name[hu]=Firefox ESR
Name[it]=Firefox ESR
Name[ja]=Firefox ESR
Name[ko]=Firefox ESR
Name[nb]=Firefox ESR
Name[nl]=Firefox ESR
Name[nn]=Firefox ESR
Name[no]=Firefox ESR
Name[pl]=Firefox ESR
Name[pt]=Firefox ESR
Name[pt_BR]=Firefox ESR
Name[sk]=Firefox ESR
Name[sv]=Firefox ESR
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
Comment[bg]=Сърфиране в Мрежата
Comment[ca]=Navegueu per el web
Comment[cs]=Prohlížení stránek World Wide Webu
Comment[de]=Im Internet surfen
Comment[el]=Περιηγηθείτε στον παγκόσμιο ιστό
Comment[es]=Navegue por la web
Comment[fi]=Selaa Internetin WWW-sivuja
Comment[fr]=Navigue sur Internet
Comment[hu]=A világháló böngészése
Comment[it]=Esplora il web
Comment[nb]=Surf på nettet
Comment[nl]=Verken het internet
Comment[nn]=Surf på nettet
Comment[no]=Surf på nettet
Comment[pl]=Przeglądanie stron WWW 
Comment[pt]=Navegue na Internet
Comment[pt_BR]=Navegue na Internet
Comment[sk]=Prehliadanie internetu
Comment[sv]=Surfa på webben
GenericName=Web Browser
GenericName[bg]=Интернет браузър
GenericName[ca]=Navegador web
GenericName[de]=Webbrowser
GenericName[es]=Navegador web
GenericName[fi]=WWW-selain
GenericName[fr]=Navigateur Web
GenericName[hu]=Webböngésző
GenericName[it]=Browser Web
GenericName[nb]=Nettleser
GenericName[nl]=Webbrowser
GenericName[nn]=Nettlesar
GenericName[no]=Nettleser
GenericName[pl]=Przeglądarka WWW
GenericName[pt]=Navegador Web
GenericName[pt_BR]=Navegador Web
GenericName[ru]=Интернет-браузер
GenericName[sk]=Internetový prehliadač
GenericName[sv]=Webbläsare
X-GNOME-FullName=Firefox ESR Web Browser
X-GNOME-FullName[bg]=Интернет браузър (Firefox ESR)
X-GNOME-FullName[ca]=Navegador web Firefox ESR
X-GNOME-FullName[es]=Navegador web Firefox ESR
X-GNOME-FullName[fi]=Firefox ESR-selain
X-GNOME-FullName[fr]=Navigateur Web Firefox ESR
X-GNOME-FullName[hu]=Firefox ESR webböngésző
X-GNOME-FullName[it]=Firefox ESR Browser Web
X-GNOME-FullName[nb]=Firefox ESR Nettleser
X-GNOME-FullName[nl]=Firefox ESR webbrowser
X-GNOME-FullName[nn]=Firefox ESR Nettlesar
X-GNOME-FullName[no]=Firefox ESR Nettleser
X-GNOME-FullName[pl]=Przeglądarka WWW Firefox ESR
X-GNOME-FullName[pt]=Firefox ESR Navegador Web
X-GNOME-FullName[pt_BR]=Navegador Web Firefox ESR
X-GNOME-FullName[ru]=Интернет-браузер Firefox ESR
X-GNOME-FullName[sk]=Internetový prehliadač Firefox ESR
X-GNOME-FullName[sv]=Webbläsaren Firefox ESR
Exec=/usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=firefox-esr
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
StartupWMClass=Firefox-esr
StartupNotify=true
```

If you don't have Firefox installed you can install a it using apt (`apt install firefox`).

Comment: Thank you very much Siracuso.. I am really thankful to you.

Comment: Glad to help, an upvote and maybe mark as resolved could help too :)